# TypeScript type-safety fails with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, type-safety

Am I wrong or does type-safety get thrown out in TypeScript when parsing JSON?

**I *should* be getting an error here, but I don't:**

```
interface Person {
  name: string
}

const person: Person = somePossibleFalsey ? JSON.parse(db.person) : undefined
```

The above does not fail a type check, when I believe it should. The `db.person` variable may not be present, which could render `person` as `undefined`. But `Person` should not be `undefined`. As far as I can tell this is because I'm using `JSON.parse`.

Just to confirm that I should get an error, here is another snippet which **correctly** gives me an error:

```
const person: Person = Math.random() > .5 ? { name: 'Arthur' } : undefined
```

The above code produces the appropriate TypsScript error:

```
Type '{ name: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person'.ts(2322)
```

Why is `JSON.parse` allowing type-safety to fail? Or is there something else at play here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the core of the question is why the second term of the ternary expression, `undefined`, is allowed to be one of the alternatives that is assigned to `Person`. [This Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31518#issuecomment-494597903) describes this as working as intended. The entire ternary expression gets the union of the first return type and the second, i.e. `any | undefined`, which collapses to `any`, which in turn makes it a valid assignment. (`any` being the weakest type of all). Conversely, if this were to be wrapped in an if-else block, the error would go off:

```
let n: number;

let x: any = {}
n = x.z ? x.z : undefined // no error

let y: any = {}
if (y.z) {
    n = y.z
} else {
    n = undefined // error
}
```

([source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31518#issuecomment-494961690))

> I’m thinking the inconsistency here is that, in the first case, the entire ternary expression is inferred as any | undefined which collapses to just any; the compiler therefore sees a single return any and all is right with the world (even though it’s not). In the second case there are two return sites: one is return any which again is fine, and one is return undefined which is not.

> I think the challenge is that a ternary isn't really a statement but an expression. An expression must have a single type; in this case that type happens to be any | undefined which is unsound simply by the nature of any. Changing this, I suspect, would be very difficult: what happens when you have a ternary in the middle of a statement, e.g. as an argument to a function? What happens when there are several ternaries in the same statement [...]

> In order to type check the above the way you suggest, the compiler would basically have to duplicate the statement and individually type check it for every combination of true/false for every single ternary in the statement. You'd have a combinatorial explosion.

> The current behavior is, I suspect, the best we're going to get.

Comment: This is actually my favourite explanation. It acknowledges the strange behaviour and provides evidence to the reason for it. My only gripe is it contains no code. A good example would be to show the alternative code; i.e the expanded if/else statement that is equivalent to the ternary but producing the error...

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse` returns an `any`. And since `any` contains any type (including undefined), `any | undefined` is the same as `any`.

Use `as` to type the `JSON.parse` result and you get the expected output:

```
const person: Person = db.person ? JSON.parse(db.person) as Person : undefined; 
// Error: Type 'Person | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person'
```

EDIT: You seem to be unclear about the `any` type. This essentially switches off all type safety. Every type can be assigned to `any` and `any` can be assigned to every type. When you do

```
const myAnyFunc = (): any => {return undefined;};
const myPerson: Person = myAnyFunc();
```

this does not create a TypeError. It's nothing special about `JSON.parse()`, just a 'problem' with anything that returns `any`.
Take a look at [this excellent TS book](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system#any) to learn more about `any`.

Comment: But the second part of that conditional explicitly attempts to assign `undefined`. Why doesn't it throw because of the possibility of `undefined` being assigned to `person`? Remember that `db` equates to `{}`, so `db.person` will not evaluate to a truthy.

Comment: I understand `any`, but `db.person` is **not** true, so the inline conditional **will** fall to `undefined`, not `any`. Why does TypeScript allow this?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#420-the-conditional-operator 。

Comment: @banyudu This is a much better answer. If you put this in a proper answer I will mark as correct. Thank you.

Comment: @shennan typecast is compile-time behavior, not runtime. So unless db.person is static, typescript doesn't know whether it's true or false.

Comment: @banyudu :-) I know TypeScript is compile time. Your link does answer my question; to summarise, inline conditionals (or ternary) operators are the issue here. It's a shame you didn't post this as it's own answer, someone has now piggy backed on your link...

Comment: @shennan it's me, lol

Comment: Someone had posted before but deleted it I believe. Was a different name.

Comment: @banyudu Thanks for being the first to properly link, have chosen a more appropriate answer.